# Load directive from ng-model in controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically load a directive.. something like this:

```
<div class="{{directive-name}}></div>
  or 
<!-- directive: {{directive-name}} -->
```

**This doesn't work,** because I guess the {{directive-name}} is replaced after angular have checked for the directive.

How can I make this work?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at $compile function.  With that you can actually manually bootstrap a function.  With your approach it's already too late.

Comment: $compile works, by using an extra "loader-directive" to wrap around. Would be nicer with a simpler approach thought.

Comment: you can also use the built-in compile function within the directive.  Then it's more automated.